# How to access resources(images/mp3) from outside the jetty webroot folder?

Tags: linux, resources, jetty

I have a Java web application placed in `/home/jetty/webapps/` folder on a Jetty server.

I want to be able to serve static files like `song.mp3, img.jpg, etc` to my web application from a folder `/media/resources/` which is completely outside the jetty web root.

Can I access resources placed outside the jetty root?
If so, how can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

yes ,you can use apache httpd server set htdoc use /media/resources/

Comment: I want this on Jetty server which I am using on embedded board

Answer (score 0):

easy, here is an example that lets you serve multiple directories aggregated together under one url

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/example-jetty-embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/SplitFileServer.java?h=jetty-9

there are other fileserver embedded examples under there as well

Comment: thanks jesse for the link. But I have not configured server using .java file. I am using jetty.xml file directly. So I will try to edit xml as per SplitFileServer.java file.

Comment: yep, same concepts...there is an example in that project for this as well: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/example-jetty-embedded/src/main/resources/fileserver.xml